# Generalized Desktop directory

Tags: python, python-3.6

Simple enough, off of my last question, I am trying to make a directory change to a players desktop or file that is similar for all, as in `C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\Tester File` but the how would I make it so that USERNAME is the username of the person's computer? I tried using %USERNAME% but I don't really know how to do that, and it didn't work, and anyway the % gave an error message (I cannot remember the message, I think it was syntax error)

I also tried using ~, but it proved to be ineffective, but it may be due to my lack of experience.

**EDIT**
I solved this issue, thanks to some very great help from @pstatix so thank you.

By using user = getpass.getuser() I was able to do something like 'C:\Users' + user + '\Documents' it made this all user friendly! Thanks!

Comment: ~ is not actually the name of the directory; it is completed by the shell. If you want to use it, you'll need to tell Python to complete it for you. You can do that with `os.path.expanduser()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `getpass` module? [getpass documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html).

```
import getpass
usr = getpass.getuser()
print usr
```

**Edit: For user specified example**

You may also be interested in using the `os` module? [os documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getlogin).

```
import os
usr = os.getlogin()
path = os.path.join('..', 'Users', usr, 'Desktop', 'Tester File')
os.chdir(path)
```

Using `os.environ` for environment variables may also prove useful. [os.environ documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-parameters) For example:

```
import os

def getUserName():
    # set possible environment variables
    for name in ('LOGNAME', 'USER', 'LNAME', 'USERNAME'):
        usr = os.environ.get(name)
        if user:
            return usr #return the variable

if __name__ == '__main__':
    usr = getUserName()
    # do remainder below
```

Comment: @RobM Do you mind specifying which example I gave worked? You can even edit your own post to specify such so that users in the future may take note. Best of luck!